# Wordpress определить TOP категорию

Tags: wordpress

Есть категории

```
- Новости
-- Спорт
```

Как мне сделать так, что бы я мог сделать условие, показывать текст или нет, в зависимости от того нахожусь я в родительнской категории или в дочерной ?

Т.е мне нужно как то определить ТОП категорию и если это категория дочерная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В нужном месте кода подставьте присвойте $catid id текущей категории и выполните этот сниппет:

```
$cat = get_category($catid);
$parent_catid = $cat->category_parent;
if ( 0 === $parent_catid ) {
    // Это категория верхнего уровня
}
```